# How to show single popup(html popup) across all tabs in safari

Tags: javascript, dom, safari

I want to show a popup dialog, singular (only one popup in a browser ,across tabs) in safari browser. Any idea how i can achieve this.
Tried with localStorage and storage event for using one variable across cross tabs. but safari doesn't call the pagehide event on closing so, am not able to set proper value for that variable.

Comment: You cant do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can achieve this by making use of service worker